# Python precision issues with float formatting

Tags: python, floating-point, precision

Please look at the below Python code that I've entered into a Python 3.6 interpreter:

```
>>> 0.00225 * 100.0
0.22499999999999998
>>> '{:.2f}'.format(0.00225 * 100.0)
'0.22'
>>> '{:.2f}'.format(0.225)
'0.23'
>>>  '{:.2f}'.format(round(0.00225 * 100.0, 10))
'0.23'
```

Hopefully you can immediately understand why I'm frustrated. I am attempting to display `value * 100.0` on my GUI, storing the full precision behind a cell but only displaying 2 decimal points (or whatever the users precision setting is). The GUI is similar to an Excel spreadsheet.

I'd prefer not to lose the precision of something like `0.22222444937645` and round by `10`, but I also don't want a value such as `0.00225 * 100.0` displaying as `0.22`.

I'm interested in hearing about a standard way of approaching a situation like this or a remedy for my specific situation. Thanks ahead of time for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using the [Decimal module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html), which "provides support for fast correctly-rounded decimal floating point arithmetic." The primary advantages of `Decimal` relevant to your use case are:

> - Decimal numbers can be represented exactly. In contrast, numbers like `1.1` and `2.2` do not have exact representations in binary floating point. End users typically would not expect `1.1 + 2.2` to display as `3.3000000000000003` as it does with binary floating point.
> - The exactness carries over into arithmetic. In decimal floating point, `0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 - 0.3` is exactly equal to zero. In binary floating point, the result is 
>   `5.5511151231257827e-017`. While near to zero, the differences prevent reliable equality testing and differences can accumulate. For this reason, decimal is preferred in accounting applications which have strict equality invariants.

Based on the information you've provided in the question, I cannot say how much of an overhaul migrating to `Decimal` would require. However, if you're creating a spreadsheet-like application and always want to preserve maximal precision, then you will probably want to refactor to use `Decimal` sooner or later to avoid unexpected numbers in your user-facing GUI.

To get the behavior you desire, you may need to change the rounding mode (which defaults to `ROUND_HALF_EVEN`) for `Decimal` instances.

```
from decimal import getcontext, ROUND_HALF_UP

getcontext().rounding = ROUND_HALF_UP

n = round(Decimal('0.00225') * Decimal('100'), 2)
print(n)  # prints Decimal('0.23')

m = round(Decimal('0.00225') * 100, 2)
print(m)  # prints Decimal('0.23')
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the information on Decimal. 
 Unfortunately `'{:.2f}'.format(Decimal(0.00225 * 100))` results in `0.22`

Comment: `'{:.2f}'.format(Decimal(Decimal('0.00225') * Decimal('100')))` yields the same result

Comment: Please read through all the documentation for the `decimal` module. You need to change the rounding mode for `Decimal` instances. I've edited my answer with details.

Comment: @Riptyde4 Did that help?

Comment: It looks like it has been working so far, yes.  thank you! still evaluating results

Comment: Re “The exactness carries over into arithmetic.”: Decimal and binary floating-point arithmetic behave the same in arithmetic. The example you show, `1.1+2.2` → `3.3`, reflects only that (a) those numerals convert exactly when converted to decimal floating-point, and (b) the sum does not spill out of the significand. (a) is a consequence of your first bullet item, and (b) is true for binary arithmetic too. Decimal arithmetic is not exact in general when calculating interest, sales tax, the unit price of something sold three for a dollar, physics simulations, or any other general calculations.

Comment: What this means for the OP is that users of their spreadsheet-like GUI will see rounding errors even if the spreadsheet is implemented with decimal arithmetic. Using decimal eliminates errors in conversions into/out of the spreadsheet but does not eliminate other errors.  In fact, fixed-point arithmetic fails in the same ways, belying the oft-repeated claim that it is exact. It is neither floating-point nor binary that causes inexactness. It is simply the limited precision. **All** arithmetic with limited precision is inexact in general, regardless of base or fixed/floating.

Answer (score -2):

perhaps use decimal? docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html

```
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 2
n = Decimal.from_float(0.00225)
m = n * 100
print(n, m)
print(m.quantize(Decimal('.01'), rounding=ROUND_DOWN))
print(m.quantize(Decimal('.01'), rounding=ROUND_UP)
```

Comment: This returns `0.22`, the desired result is `0.23`

Comment: then ROUND_UP, if you round it up it does 0.23